# Recover Live Photos which have been split in two files (JPEG+MP4)

Tags: icloud, photos.app

Some years ago I was using Google Photos to store my pics (shot with an iPhone).

Now I have moved everything to iCloud, but I have the old Live Photos in two different files:

- An .mp4 file, which is the "live video" of 2 seconds
- A .jpeg file, which is the photo, but it is not recognized as a Live Photo

I would like to know if by any chance there is the possibility to "mix" again the .mp4 and .jpeg files, in order to restore the original Live Photos.

Comment: Try https://apps.apple.com/us/app/intolive-live-wallpapers/id1061859052 . Allow access to your photo library. Go to Albums > Videos > [Select one] > Make > Save Live Photo to library

Comment: Please focus on one question per post.

Comment: Try exporting the live photo and video (export originals) as files, make sure the file names are the same (different extensions) then reimport them at the same time. You could do this for a single live photo + video and see if that has any effect

Comment: @Ezekiel unfortunately I've tried, but it seems to be not effective :(